# Match and Add elements with dynamic namespace using xslt

Tags: xslt

I have some xml as follows...

```
<ns1:service1 xmlns:ns1="http://foo.com/service_1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ns1:SystemInfo>
    <ns1:functionMode>Y</ns1:functionMode>
</ns1:SystemInfo>
</ns1:service>
```

Now I need to take it and do 2 things

1. Wrap in a SOAP envelope
2. insert a trans tag in SystemInfo

the following works for wrapping...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name = "transId" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
     <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
         <xsl:copy-of select="/*"/>
       </soapenv:Body>
     </soapenv:Envelope>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now I need to add the tag, problem is we do not know what the Namespace is (and it could change per request). So I can't hardcode it. However, it will already be in the root tag.

So after I would want...

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:service1 xmlns:ns1="http://foo.com/service_1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ns1:SystemInfo>
         <ns1:trans />
     <ns1:functionMode>Y</ns1:functionMode>
  </ns1:SystemInfo>
    </ns1:service>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But this doesn't seem to accomplish it....

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='SystemInfo']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:element name="type"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="copy-children"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Copy the children of the current node. -->
<xsl:template name="copy-children">
  <xsl:copy-of select="./*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

What should the above be instead?

Comment: Why are you inventing `copy-children` rather than `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>` and letting the identity template deal with them?

Comment: You also have something of a conflict between the identity template and your `match="*"` template. I presume the latter was intended to be `match="/"` -- ie, match the root node to apply a wrapper around the entire document.

Comment: ... And what's the non-namespaced `<type>` element about? That seems to be where you intended to construct the `ns1:trans`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead if using **xsl:copy-of** which will just copy the current element without allowing you to make any changes, use **xsl:apply-templates**

```
  <soapenv:Body>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </soapenv:Body>
```

Then you can write a template to match your **SystemInfo** element, and add whatever new elements you need. You could even make use of the **namespace-uri** function to add it with the same namespace.

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='SystemInfo']">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:element name="trans" namespace="{namespace-uri()}" />
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="transId"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soapenv:Header/>
      <soapenv:Body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='SystemInfo']">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:element name="trans" namespace="{namespace-uri()}" />
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Great answer! I will confirm and then give the check!